# Onbeforeunload not firing in IE when user closes window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, onbeforeunload

I monitor each field in my form for changes by binding to the 'change' event for all input fields, and set a flag if anything gets modified.
I then bind to window.onbeforeunload and check that flag, returning the warning if the flag is set.  Per the Jquery API documentation, I'm binding directly to window.onbeforeunload versus $(window) to avoid memory issues.

For this I have the following code:

```
$(':input').change(function(){
    if($('#editObject_blah').attr('value') == 0){
        $('#editObject_blah').attr('value',1)};
    }
);
window.onbeforeunload=verifyexit;
function verifyexit() {
    if($('#editObject_blah').attr('value') == 1){
        return'You have not saved your changes!';
    }
};
```

EDIT:  The element editObject_blah is actually this:

```
<form id="editObject_blah" onSubmit="return false;" value=0>
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but fails to catch the user closing the browser window in IE 7.

I should note that the above code is called via an eval() as the result of an ajax request, versus being loaded via an inline script tag.  I don't think that should make a difference, but that's why I'm asking here.

Thank you.

Comment: It worked inline for me. Note that i removed if condition in verifyexit.

Comment: `$('#editObject_blah').attr('value')` why are you doing that and not `$('#editObject_blah').val()`?

Comment: habit.  attr is universal and I set alot of other stuff.

Comment: If you're working with jQuery 1.6 or newer, you should definitely get out of that habit.

Comment: Is there any reason why `attr('value')` wouldn't work in a place where `val()` would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use ".attr()" to get the "value" property:

```
if ($('#editObject_blah').val() == 1) {
  return "whatever";
}
```

If your handler does not return a string, then the browser assumes you're OK with the user closing the window.

If that's not an `<input>`, then you should probably store the flag with ".data()" instead. To do that, you'd just pick a name for the flag:

```
$(':input').change(function(){
  $('#editObject_blah').data("changed", 1);
});

function verifyexit() {
  if($('#editObject_blah').data('changed') == 1){
    return "You have not saved changes yet!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Modified the code to use val instead of attr('value') as requested.  No change.

Comment: @Daren: which DOM Element is `editObject_blah` ? does it have a val at all? the code is ok otherwise

Comment: I was actually using the form element to store that 'value'.  If I use an input then I'd have to limit the scope of my change function or else it would be self triggering would it not?

Comment: What sort of element is that?  The `<form>` element?  I'll update my post.

Comment: Used your code.  Same result.  Works in Firefox.. doesn't fire in IE.

Comment: Well you need to apply some debugging energy for the IE case then - it's clearly the case that inside the handler, it's not detecting that flag you're setting.

Comment: removed the if so the handler now just has function() {return 'Blah'};  Same result!

Comment: Well then there must be something about the way you're running that code that's making it not work. The "onbeforeunload()" feature definitely does work in IE7.